# vb.net can't get database value in OR statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i have `kriteria` database with column name `kode` which contain value `kriteria 1` to `kriteria 6`

I want user can pick 3 to 6 value from `kode` and it will show in datagridview as matrix...

if user pick 6 kriteria there's no problem and it show matrix 6x6 [image: like this]
...but if user pick less than 6 kriteria or parameters empty, it shows nothing...

this is my code

```
Private Sub perhitungankriteria_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each item In menuuser.ListBox2.Items
            list2.Add(item)
        Next
        connect()

    End Sub

    Sub connect()
        Dim adapter As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT kode FROM kriteria WHERE kode=@kriteria1 OR kode=@kriteria2 OR kode=@kriteria3 OR kode=@kriteria4 OR kode=@kriteria5 OR kode=@kriteria6", konek)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(0)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria2", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria3", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(2)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria4", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(3)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria5", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(4)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria6", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(5)
        adapter = cmd.ExecuteReader

        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

        While adapter.Read
            list.Add(adapter("kode"))
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(adapter("kode"), adapter("kode"))
        End While
```

i've try IN instead WHERE query in sql SELECT statement but same problems appears

Comment: When the user picks fewer than 6 items what does `list2(5)` contain?

Comment: list2(5) is empty if user pick less than 6 items sir

Comment: If kriteria not selected, parameter returns Null? Possible options are to make sure each parameter returns something other than Null (perhaps concatenating an empty string will resolve) OR conditionally build the criteria string.

Comment: Have you checked that the kriteria are being returned in order?  For example, if you only have kodes in kriteria 1,2 and 4 is the value in kirteria4 actually in list2(3)?

Answer (score 0):

Call BuildCommand from a button click after the user has made selections from the list box.

```
Dim list2() As String = {"kriteria1", "kriteria2", "kriteria3", "kriteria4", "kriteria5", "kriteria6"}
    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.DataSource = list2

Private Sub BuildCommand()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder("SELECT kode FROM kriteria WHERE kode = ")
        Dim ct As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(0)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria2", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria3", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(2)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria4", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(3)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria5", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(4)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kriteria6", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = list2(5)
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(0)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria1 OR kode = ")
        End If
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(1)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria2 OR kode = ")
        End If
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(2)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria3 OR kode = ")
        End If
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(3)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria4 OR kode = ")
        End If
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(4)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria5 OR kode = ")
        End If
        If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(5)) Then
            sb.Append("@kriteria6;")
        End If
        Dim strSQL As String = sb.ToString
        If strSQL.EndsWith("= ") Then
            Dim index As Integer = strSQL.LastIndexOf("O") 'last capital O
            strSQL = strSQL.Remove(index)
            strSQL &= ";"
        End If
        Debug.Print(strSQL) 'Check the immediate window
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL
        cmd.Connection = cn
        'use your command as you wish
    End Sub
```